# 「認識できません」の意味の広さ

Tags: meaning, usage

例えば、パソコンのグラフィックボードを挿しているけど、壊れていて、「認識できません」というエラーが出てもおかしくないと思います。

この「認識できません」は一義的にcannot recognizeという意味になりますか。それとも、最初から挿していなかった場合、"cannot detect"という意味としても「認識できません」という表現を使いますか。

このような文脈で、それ以外の意味もありますか。

Answer (score 2):

質問への答えとしては、デバイスの出すメッセージに用いられた場合の「認識しない」に特に多義性はないと思います。

ただ、「認識しない（できない）」という表現を質問されているような状況で使うことにそれほど違和感はないものの、デバイスが出すメッセージとしては「Xを認識できません」よりは「Xを検出できません/Xは検出されませんでした」のほうがよく見る気がします（例：ディスプレイへの入力がないときのメッセージ「入力が検出されません」）。細かく言えば"cannot detect X/X is not detected"のほうに近い表現です。（英語でも同じかと思いますがどうでしょう。）

「認識する」は、ユーザーの視点で「USBメモリが認識されない」のような形では「検出する」よりも多く使われると思います。

Answer (score 2):

It's very common to see this error message when a device is physically not inserted, a cable is not plugged, etc. From the computer's point of view, it is usually impossible to tell if the device is broken or not inserted. Practically speaking, when you see a message like this, you need to ensure the device is physically inserted before anything. I expect a more friendly error message when the machine at least knows something is inserted but cannot recognize what it is (e.g., このディスクの再生は非対応です, 対応していないケーブルが挿入されています or at least **この**デバイスは認識できません).